# How to Join to first row qlikview and remove duplicates

Tags: qlikview

How to Join to first row qlikview

I have the follwoing script

```
sales :  
Load *  

from test.qvd ;  

LEFT  JOIN(sales )  
IntervalMatch (datecol)  
LOAD DISTINCT [DATE DEBUT]  
      ,[DATE FIN]  
 resident      OC  
      ;  
      LEFT JOIN (sales )  
LOAD *  
RESIDENT OC;
```

I got duplicates rows . so how to Join to first row in qlikview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming `residents` have multiple `sales`. You can always GROUP BY whatever is duplicating and resolve the issue.

Comment: how to know the columns are duplicating ?